# VBScript to modify an Element (of many, with same Element names but with different Attributes)?

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript, filter

I need to write a simple VBScript to modify an existing XML file. I am able to write a VBScript to modify an element, but the problem I am currently encountering is that I have multiple elements with the same Element/tag names but different ATTRIBUTES as the below XML document sample shows:

```
<MyDoc>
   <Section name="First">
      <....../>
  </Section>
  <Section name ="Second">
     <......>
     <Parameter name="Service" value="MsrNdp.dll"/>
   </Section>
 </MyDoc>
```

Let's assume I wanted to change ONLY the "value" of the parameter "Service" to "LdrXMP.dll" (then save it): Since there is more than one Element called "Section", how would I specify that I am reffering to the Element "Section" whose attribute value = "Second" ??

I have the following simple VBScript code so far: How can I tweak my code below to get what I want? Thanks for your help.

```
Set xmlDoc = _
  CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load("C:\Users\Frank\Desktop\MyDoc.xml")
Set colNodes=xmlDoc.selectNodes _
("/MyDoc/Section ")
For Each objNode in colNodes
   objNode.Text = "LdrXMP.dll"
Next
xmlDoc.Save "C:\Users\Frank\Desktop\MyDoc.xml"
```

Comment: I recommend using XSLT for this kind of tasks. Pros: Easy, short, readable and maintainable. Cons: None that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Use an XPath search expression that referes to the name attribute, selectSingleNode(), and getAttributeNode() as in:

```
  Dim oFS      : Set oFS      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim sFSpec   : sFSpec       = goFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\testdata\xml\so14541579.xml")
  Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  objMSXML.async = False

  objMSXML.load sFSpec

  If 0 = objMSXML.parseError Then
     Dim sXPath : sXPath    = "/MyDoc/Section[@name=""Second""]/Parameter"
     Dim ndFnd  : Set ndFnd = objMSXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
     If ndFnd Is Nothing Then
        WScript.Echo sXPath, "not found"
     Else
        WScript.Echo ndFnd.getAttributeNode("value").value
        ndFnd.getAttributeNode("value").value = "abracadabra.dll"
        WScript.Echo objMSXML.xml
     End If
  Else
     WScript.Echo objMSXML.parseError.reason
  End If
```

output:

```
MsrNdp.dll
<MyDoc>
        <Section name="First">
                <Parameter name="Service" value="MsrNdp.dll"/>
        </Section>
        <Section name="Second">
                <Parameter name="Service" value="abracadabra.dll"/>
        </Section>
</MyDoc>
```